# Evaluating the length of rows within and dimensions of lists of lists

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, error-handling, user-defined-functions

I need to develop a function that takes two lists of lists, and generates a ValueError if:

1. The list of lists have incomparable dimensions
2. The rows in the lists do not have the same length

The function needs to be in vanilla python and cannot use any libraries

Answer (score 0):

```
def evaluateListsDimensions(first, second):
    
    # Compute both row numbers
    firstSize = len(first)
    secondSize = len(second)
    
    # If those do not match raise ValueError
    if firstSize != secondSize:
        raise ValueError
    
    # If the lists have al least 1 row check their dimensions
    elif firstSize != 0:
   
        # All rows have to be the same size
        sizeToMach = len(first[0])
        allSizesFirst = all(len(list)== sizeToMach for list in first)
        
        # Raise ValueError if at least one was not of the correct size
        if not allSizesFirst:
            raise ValueError
        
        # Check the second group of rows
        # This solution is if you want the the size of both lists is the same
        # Otherwise uncomment the next line 
        # sizeToMatch = len(second[0]) 
        allSizesSecond = all(len(list)== sizeToMach for list in second)
        
        # Raise ValueError if at least one was not of the correct size 
        if not allSizesSecond:
            raise ValueError
```

If you want you can add a custom message for your ValueError using this line:

```
raise ValueError('List with wrong dimensions')
```